# Javascript event that is triggered when browser loads new inline (ajax) content?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, events, jquery-events

Is there a Javascript event that is triggered when browser loads new inline (ajax) content? I would like to catch new content as it happens inside my browser extension. Thanks to all

```
window.onload = function() {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        alert("hello");
    });

    var config = {
        attributes: true,
        childList: true,
        characterData: true
    };

    observer.observe($('#contentArea'), config);
}
```

Comment: It depends on what that content is, but you most likely want the **[DOM Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)**.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I just realized chrome has an event for this, thanks anyways. I just thought there is a native js func for it, guess not.

Comment: @user9852405 The linked Mutation Observer is the native JS solution you are looking for. Please click that link above and start reading…

Comment: There won't be anything native in JS because you are asking about a browser event. So, you need to look to the browser for that. Mutation Observers are the standard way to do this.

Comment: @feeela Mutation Observers (or anything relating to the DOM) is not native to JS. They are supplied by the client. JavaScript has nothing in it that relates to browsers or the DOM.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Probably we have a different definition of "native". JavaScript is not ECMAScript! JavaScript is a funny conglomerate of a scripting language based on a myriad of specifications. The core is defined in ECMAScript, while DOMObserver is defined in the DOM specification. Nonetheless this is implemented natively in most clients (written in C or something) and thus could be called "native JS", since one doesn't need to include a seperate library. (Contrary to e.g. React.js, …)

Comment: @ScottMarcus isn't that related to firefox browser? i see it's documented at mozilla's site.

Comment: @user9852405 The Mozilla Developer Network is a good ressource for such kind of knowledge. This does not mean it is only available in Fx. If you scroll down far enough, you will find a browser compatibility table.

Comment: @user9852405 The Mozilla Foundation is the organization that took over the "stewardship" of the Netscape code base when Netscape went under. Netscape was the creator of JavaScript and so, Mozilla is considered an authoritative source on the matter. When you look at any of the documentation on MDN, if you scroll down to the bottom, you will see that they correlated their topic to the various standards.

Comment: @feeela Unfortunately, your description of JavaScript is not quite accurate. JavaScript is an ECMAScript complaint implementation. It is not based on any "myriad" of specifications. Various specifications exist and are implemented by the clients. The JavaScript runtime has no built-in knowledge of any of them. That's why you can have Node.js (where there is no DOM). You are confusing client implemented API's with the JavaScript runtime. API's are just that, Application Programming Interfaces, they are not part of any native language.

Comment: I could have supplied you with **[this link](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#mutationobserver)** instead of the MDN one, but most people don't want to read right from the spec. As you can see, Mutation Observers are part of a standard API that all modern browsers implement.

Comment: I added some code which is not working for me. i don't get alerts when the content changes inline.

Comment: @user9852405 It didn't work because you tried to pass it a JQuery object and not a DOM node. Then, you have to actually mutate the DOM. See my answer below for a working example.

Comment: @ScottMarcus nvm, i fixed it. i had to set the "subtree" to true in the config object. thank you everyone for helping me, love ya'll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the **[DOM Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)** will most likely be what you want.

```js
// Since you are using JQuery, use the document.ready event handler
// which fires as soon as the DOM is fully parsed, which is before
// the load event fires.
$(function() {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        alert("DOM has been mutated!");
    });

    var config = {
        attributes: true,
        childList: true,
        characterData: true
    };

    // You must pass a DOM node to observe, not a JQuery object
    // So here, I'm adding [0] to extract the first Node from 
    // the JQuery wrapped set of nodes.
    observer.observe($('#contentArea')[0], config);
    
    // Then, the DOM has to be mutated in some way:
    $("#contentArea").html("<p>test</p>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentArea"></div>
```